# Does not have a member named

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, member

I'm creating simple app with passing data and I don't have idea how to fix it. In this code.

```
       (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).url = (self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Program).url
```

I've got this error.!

"'DetailViewController' does not have a member named 'url'" Here's my code

```
 class Program: NSObject {
var name: NSString
var url: NSString

init(name:NSString, url:NSString) {
    self.name = name
    self.url = url
}
```

}

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    var arrayOfPrograms: NSArray = []
    @IBOutlet weak var ViewController: UITableView?
    var color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var sideMenu : SideMenu?
    var bannerView:ADBannerView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //Písmo v Navigation bare.
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)!,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = color
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.bannerView?.delegate = self
        self.bannerView?.hidden = true

        /*
        sideMenu = SideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuData: ["Slovenské Televízie", "České televízie", "Nemecké televízie"])
        sideMenu!.delegate = self
        */
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true  // Zmiznutie Navigation baru na pohyb prsta nahor.

        self.arrayOfPrograms = [Program(name: "Markíza", url: "http://1.com")]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.arrayOfPrograms.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        let imageName = UIImage(named: (self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Program).name)

        cell.imageView.image = imageName
        cell.textLabel.text = (self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Program).name
        cell.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15)
        cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 101.0/255.0, green: 112.0/255.0, blue: 122.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0);
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0);
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Kategória  ★★★☆☆"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 10)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 101.0/255.0, green: 112.0/255.0, blue: 122.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0);
        cell.detailTextLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0);
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

        var myBackView=UIView(frame:cell.frame)
        myBackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 81.0/255.0, green: 196.0/255.0, blue: 212.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0);
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
        return cell
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    }
    /*
    func sideMenuDidSelectItemAtIndex(index: Int) {
        sideMenu?.toggleMenu()
        if index == 1 {
            let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
        */

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.bannerView?.hidden = false
    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return willLeave
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        self.bannerView?.hidden = true
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow() as NSIndexPath!
        var destinationViewController: DetailViewController
        (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).url = (self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Program).url
    }
}
```

I can't solve this.

If I do this:

```
class DetailViewController {
    var url: NSString

    init(url:NSString) {
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

I'll get Invalid redeclaration of 'DetailViewController'

DetailViewController

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate{

var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!
var color = UIColor.whiteColor()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = color
       self.navigationItem.title = (self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex as Program).name

       var url = NSURL(self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex as Program).url
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

        moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        moviePlayer.view.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
        moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    }
```

Comment: Your class `Program` defines `url`. Perhaps your class `DetailViewController` does not?

Comment: The error message describes the problem. Your `DetailViewController` does not have a member named `url`. You need to add one similar to how you added one for `Program`.

Comment: check my edit.. and I'm sorry I'm beginner

Comment: Please show your real code for DetailViewController. What you have shown so far is not it. Copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this as a compile error, then DetailViewController does not define a property called url.
If you get the error during execution, then the destinationViewController is not a DetailViewController.  Set a breakpoint and check what type it really is.

Comment: check on my edit.I show all my codes. How can i define a property for DetailViewController?

Comment: ?? you have two properties already, moviePlayer and color. Why do you have a problem defining a third??

Comment: But I want property that will fix "'DetailViewController' does not have a member named 'url'" this error

Comment: Then do what I said, add a property named 'url'

Comment: Okey I fixed it.Thanks a lot but I have a last problem. In line "var url = NSURL(self.arrayOfPrograms.objectAtIndex as Program).url" I've got error Could not find member url.

Comment: There are three errors in that single line of code. Please go and read the Swift programming manual (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) from cover to cover. Don't expect us to debug stuff if you don't know what you are talking about yourself.